# Detach from spring-boot screen in ubuntu

Tags: spring, spring-boot, screen, ubuntu-14.04

I am running a spring-boot project by using following command

```
spring-boot:run
```

It's running perfectly.My question is how to detach from that screen?

I have tried `Ctrl+A followed by D.` It's not working.

If I close the terminal the application is also shutting down.

I have tried also `Ctrl+A followed by Ctrl+Z`. It's also not working.It's stopping the application by force not detaching.

Any other ways?

Comment: try alt+f2 and enter xkill and terminate the application

Comment: I don't want to terminate the application.I just want to detach the screen.The application should run @IsuruMadusanka

Comment: First Google result for "detach unix": http://serverfault.com/q/34750

Comment: I think you need to run your application in background if it is do "$spring-boot:run &"

Comment: @kryger. Not helpful.Please note that I want to run my application run in the background.The link says how to detach linux not detach screen if I am not wrong.

Comment: @IsuruMadusanka .Can you show me which command should I use to run in background.It's showing `-boot:run: command not found`.

Answer (score 3):

Best thing you can do is run the command in background and then take a look at log file separately. As Madusanka said, you can run in background by adding `'&'` at the end of the command

```
spring-boot:run &
```

Else you can tail it to a file,

```
spring-boot:run >> /tmp/log.txt &
```

or, as Kryger says, user `CTRL+Z` to run in background and type `bg`.